# How to duplicate fields names with proto3 oneof feature?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3

Proto3 supports the oneof features, where you can have a message with many fields and where at most one field will be set at the same time.

Since one field will be set at a time, it would be reasonable to have duplicate field names in the proto schema. The problem is the proto generater sees this as a redefinition.

I'd like to do this because in my situation, this makes json serialization with `JsonFormat` simple.

For example, I may like to have

```
message MyResponse {
    int32 a = 1;
    string b = 2;
    oneof Properties {
        PropertiesType1 properties = 3;
        PropertiesType2 properties = 4;
        PropertiesType3 properties = 5;
        PropertiesType4 properties = 6;
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this, or will have to make the effort of redefining the proto? A possible work around may be for example to use `map<string, Properties> properties = 9;`

Comment: did you find any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: What you need is "sum type/discriminated union/tagged union" which unfortunately is not supported by protobuf. See https://rainway.com/blog/2021/05/26/schema-language-unions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved similar use case for JSON serialization using this way.

```
message MyResponse {
    int32 a = 1;
    string b = 2;
    oneof Properties {
        PropertiesType1 properties1 = 3 [json_name = "properties"];
        PropertiesType2 properties2 = 4 [json_name = "properties"];
        PropertiesType3 properties3 = 5 [json_name = "properties"];
        PropertiesType4 properties4 = 6 [json_name = "properties"];
    }
}
```

This would work if you use protoc compilers but it wont work for advanced tools like buf lint/build. Hope this helps.

But as @marc gravell said this is not recommended way.

Comment: This would break JSON parsing, so I'm actually surprised that it doesn't throw an error. It's either an oversight/bug, or a deliberate feature to support exactly this use case.

Answer (score 4):

Ignore the JSON but for now; in most languages/frameworks, you are going to access those properties *by their name*, whether that is getting the value, or checking which one is set. If the names conflict: you can't do that.

Also: `anyof` allows the same type to be used for multiple of the members in a discriminated union, in which case what you want to do gets ever more confusing.

Finally, going back to JSON: the parser sees `"properties":` - *what does it expect next*? *And once it has parsed the value, what field is considered "set" in the discriminated union?*

So no, for many reasons: this isn't allowed.